# DataTables add tag to column based on another attribute's value

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, datatables

I am trying to get the `<span>` tag into the `"salesStatusName"` column cell that already has some data in it. The tag should be placed in there when the value of the last column `"completelyDelivered"` is true. However, I also don't want `"completelyDelivered"` to even be a column in the table, so I assume I somehow need to access the value of `"completelyDelivered"` attribute in the received JSON.

How it looks now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMNvo.png circle in a separate column

How I want it to look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVpAW.png circle within Status Name column

I looked around and there are very similar questions, but I was unable to implement any solution.

DataTables instantiation code:
Note that I use AJAX and get JSON code returned

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('MM-DD-YYYY');

    var datatableObj = $('#salesOrdersTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Orders/GetAll",
            "type": "GET",
            error: function (error) {
                RedirectUserToErrorPage();
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "salesOrderNumber" },
            { "data": "salesOrderNumber" },
            { "data": "poNumber" },
            { "data": "orderDateString" },
            { "data": "company" },
            { "data": "salesPerson" },
            { "data": "salesStatusName" },
            { "data": "completelyDelivered" }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": 0, //salesOrderNumber col
                "orderable": false, 
                "render": function (data) {
                    return '<input type="button" value="+" onclick="location.href=\'/Shipments/Get?salesOrderNumber=' + data + '\'">';
                }
            },
            {
                "targets": 7, //completelyDelivered col
                "render": function (data) {
                    if (String(data) == "true") {
                        return '<span class="SalesOrderDelivered">⬤</span>';                           
                    }
                    return "";
                }
            },
            { className: "salesOrderNumber", "targets": 1 },
        ],
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some research and figured it out.

Basically, if you write `{ "data": null },` as a definition for a column, you gain access to all properties of that row. So, in `"render": function(data)` function, write `data["propertyName"]` to get the value.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('MM-DD-YYYY');

    var datatableObj = $('#salesOrdersTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Orders/GetAll",
            "type": "GET",
            error: function (error) {
                RedirectUserToErrorPage();
            }
        },
        {"data": "salesOrderNumber",},
            { "data": "salesOrderNumber" },
            { "data": "poNumber" },
            { "data": "orderDateString" },
            { "data": "company" },
            { "data": "salesPerson" },
            { "data": null, },//this is Sales Status column.
                //"data: null" accesses all JSON data. We need this so that in "columnDefs" section
                //we can use the values of both "completelyDelivered" and "salesStatusName" properties.
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": 0, //button col
                "orderable": false,
                "render": function (data) {
                    return '<input type="button" value="+" onclick="location.href=\'/Shipments/GetShipments?salesOrderNumber=' + data + '\'">';
                }
            },
            {
                "targets": 6, //Sales Status col. 
                "render": function (data) { //This is where we can use values of "completelyDelivered" and "salesStatusName" JSON properties.
                    if (String(data["completelyDelivered"]) == "true") {
                        return (String(data["salesStatusName"]) + '<span class="AllDelivered">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;⬤</span>');
                    } else {
                        return String(data["salesStatusName"]);
                    }
                }
            },
            { className: "salesOrderNumber", "targets": 1 },
        ],
    });
```